# Hibernate: in HQL how to select from named query

Tags: hibernate, hql

We are using Hibernate 3.2.5

We have 2 entities EntityA and EntityB:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="entities">
    <class name="EntityA" mutable="false">
        <subselect>
            SELECT id, dataA FROM DataA
        </subselect>
        <id name="id"></id>
        <property name="dataA" />

        <sql-query name="getEntityA_2">
            <return class="entities.EntityA" />
            SELECT id, dataA FROM DataA WHERE condition = true
        </sql-query>
    </class>

    <class name="EntityB" mutable="false">
        <subselect>
            SELECT id, dataB, idA FROM DataB
        </subselect>
        <id name="id"></id>
        <property name="dataB" />
        <property name="idA" />

        <sql-query name="getEntityB_2">
            <return class="entities.EntityB" />
            SELECT id, dataB, idA FROM DataB WHERE condition = true
        </sql-query>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And I need to write a named HQL query that would reference named query "getEntityA_2".

I've checked Hiberante docs "10.4.1.7. Externalizing named queries" there's written:

> Also note that a query declaration inside a  element requires a global unique name for the query, while a query declaration inside a  element is made unique automatically by prepending the fully qualified name of the class, for example eg.Cat.ByNameAndMaximumWeight.

I tried this:

```
<query name="getEntytyB_withABcond">
    SELECT b.id, b.dataB, b.idA
    FROM
        EntityB b, EntityA.getEntityA_2 aCond
    WHERE aCond.id = b.idA
      AND b.condition = true
</query>
```

But I get error:

> Error in named query: getEntytyB_withABcond
>
> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: EntityA.getEntityA_2 aCond is not mapped ...

Instead of "EntityA.getEntityA_2" I also tried simply "getEntityA_2" and "entities.EntityA.getEntityA_2". Won't work too.

Question: **Is there a way to select from named query in HQL? How?**